# Selenium webdriver: Unable to detect frameset

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a page that needs to be automated using *Selenium Webdriver*.

My HTML for the page (inspect by Firebug):

```
<html>
<head>....</head>
<frameset onload="DO_Box.setReadyState()" rows="*,0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0" name="frmMaster">
    <frame src="/SomeSource.jsp" marginheight="1" marginwidth="2" scrolling="no" name="frmContent">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Here i have tried `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()` and then `driver.SwitchTo().frame()`. Tried to locate frame by index, frame name, Xpath, classname, name but all in vain.

My driver is unable to locate the parent frame and thereby any elements in it. Please help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need switch to `frameset`. You can directly switch to `frame` and find the element as below :-

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frmContent");
// do your stuff here
..................
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

**Edited** :- if `frame` take time to load, try with `WebDriverWait` to wait until `frame` exists as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

IWebElement frame = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Name("frmContent")));
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
// do your stuff here
..................
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: That Worked like a charm:) Thanks

Comment: @AnilVaddepally you welcome. Glad to help you.. please accept the answer as well if it helped...http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work...:)